# AWS Tag in amazon-product-api NPM

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I use [**amazon-product-api**](https://github.com/t3chnoboy/amazon-product-api) NPM.

```
var amazon = require('amazon-product-api');

var client = amazon.createClient({
  awsId: "aws ID",
  awsSecret: "aws Secret",
  awsTag: "aws Tag"
});
```

What is **awsTag**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is [Associate Tag](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/AssociateTag.html)

> An AssociateTag is an alphanumeric token distributed by Amazon that
>   uniquely identifies an Associate. Amazon uses this ID to credit an
>   Associate for a sale. The AssociateTag parameter becomes part of the
>   PurchaseURL, which is the URL used to purchase the items in a remote
>   shopping cart

.

Comment: My AssociateTag seems to be: yubi07-21

Comment: Then use your `AssociateTag`. Does it answer your question?